# How can I capture the RejectedExecutionException thrown in a CompletableFuture's whenCompleteAsync invocation?

Tags: java, java-8, future, executorservice, completable-future

Following example code I'm injecting a `biconsumer` which sleeps for 100 millis as a completion action of a set of completable future. I've used `whenCompleteAsync` method by giving a separate `executorService` to use. `executorService` is a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with core pool size 5, max size 5 and queue length of 1.

```
public class CompleteTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 5, 10,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1));

        ArrayList<CompletableFuture<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i <100; i++) {
            CompletableFuture<String> stringCompletableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
            stringCompletableFuture.whenCompleteAsync((e, a) -> {
                System.out.println("Complete " + e);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}
            }, executorService);

            list.add(stringCompletableFuture);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            list.get(i).complete(i + "");
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran the code, even though I'm completing 100 futures only 6 outputs get printed. That is 5 core threads and 1 queued one. What happens to the rest? If other runnables could not submitted to the executor service because of the queue already full, shouldn't be there an exception.?

OutPut

```
Complete 0
Complete 1
Complete 2
Complete 3
Complete 4
Complete 5
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An exception is thrown, and a `CompletableFuture` is completed exceptionally, just not any of those you're tracking.

You're instantiating and initializing a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with a constructor which uses a default `RejectedExecutionHandler` that simply throws an exception. We know that a `RejectedExecutionException` is thrown if an `ExecutorService` cannot accept a task. So where is the task added and where is the exception thrown?

As it stands, all of the chaining happens within `whenCompleteAsync`. When you call that, you add a dependent to the receiver `CompletableFuture`, `stringCompletableFuture`. When `stringCompletableFuture` is completed (successfully, in this case), it will create a new `CompletableFuture` (which it returns) and attempt to schedule the given `BiConsumer` on the given `ExecutorService`.

Since the `ExecutorService`'s queue has no space, it will invoke the `RejectedExecutionHandler` which will throw `RejectedExecutionException`. That exception is captured at that time and used to `completeExceptionally` the  `CompletableFuture` that will be returned.

In other words, in your `for` loop, capture the `CompletableFuture` returned by `whenCompleteAsync`, store it, and print out its state.

```
ArrayList<CompletableFuture<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<CompletableFuture<?>> dependents = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i <100; i++) {
    CompletableFuture<String> stringCompletableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
    CompletableFuture<?> thisWillHaveException = stringCompletableFuture.whenCompleteAsync((e, a) -> {
        System.out.println("Complete " + e);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {e1.printStackTrace();}
    }, executorService);
    dependents.add(thisWillHaveException);
    list.add(stringCompletableFuture);
}

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    list.get(i).complete(i + "");
}
Thread.sleep(2000);
dependents.forEach(cf -> {
    cf.whenComplete((r, e) -> {
        if (e != null)
            System.out.println(cf + " " + e.getMessage());
    });
});
```

You'll notice that they are all (except the 6 that were successfully printed earlier) completed exceptionally with a `RejectedExecutionException`.

```
...
java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@2d8e6db6[Completed exceptionally] java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete@3f91beef rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4eec7777[Running, pool size = 5, active threads = 5, queued tasks = 1, completed tasks = 0]
java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@23ab930d[Completed exceptionally] java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete@1a6c5a9e rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4eec7777[Running, pool size = 5, active threads = 5, queued tasks = 1, completed tasks = 0]
java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@4534b60d[Completed exceptionally] java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete@37bba400 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4eec7777[Running, pool size = 5, active threads = 5, queued tasks = 1, completed tasks = 0]
```